# Google Translate not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm having troubles using Google Translate on my site: I'm trying to achieve this by detecting if the cookie "googtrans" is set to something and it works, but the problem is that the page doesn't keep the last language selected. From what I've read, Google Translate checks the content of the cookie and base on that to decide whether to put "Español" or "English", etc.

This is my code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script src="./source/build/js/app.cookies.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        if(getCookie("googtrans") != ""){
            console.log("Language Selected")    
        }else{
            new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                pageLanguage: '/es', 
            includedLanguages: 'en,es,de',
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 
                'google_translate_element');
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

In the cookies file I have some basic functions to create, get and delete cookies with js.

I read a few posts about this and tried them but none of them work.